# converting from string to an array react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I get this string from an api [10, 20, 22, 26]. These values are assigned to [A, B, C, D] and I have a slider that has these values [1, 2, 3 ,4].
What I need is when you select 1 in the slider, it gives you the value of A (which is 10 in this case). If you select 2 in the slider it should give you the value of B (which is 20), and so on.
i can do this when i mock the data `const valuesFromApi = [ 10,20, 22];` but i cant do the same with the data from my api, i guess that is because its a string and not an array.

this is my code

```
    const Calculadora = ({navigation}) => {
  const [sliderValue, setsliderValue] = useState();
  const [sliderValue2, setsliderValue2] = useState(A);
  const [A, setvA] = useState();
  const [B, setvB] = useState();
  const [C, setvC] = useState();
  const [D, setvD] = useState();
  const [pterms, setpterms] = useState([]);
  const valuesFromApi = [ 10,20, 22];
  const [value, setValue] = useState(valuesFromApi[0]);
```

this is how i get the data from api

```
useEffect(() => { 
    async function BCcontroller() {
       const vCreationUser = 6;
       const vSolicitudeId = 8;
       const { data } = await ForceApi.post(`/ConsultBCController.php`, {vSolicitudeId, vCreationUser});
            const values = data.terms;
            setpterms(data.terms);
            console.log(setpterms);
            const [termA, termB, termC, termD] = values.split(',');
            setvA(Number(termA));
            setvB(Number(termB));
            setvC(Number(termC));
            setvD(Number(termD));
    }
    BCcontroller();
}, []);
```

and this is my slider

```
<View style={{alignItems: 'stretch', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                        <Slider 
                            maximumValue={D > 0 ? 4: 3 }
                            minimumValue={1}
                            step={1}
                            value={pterms.indexOf(value)}
                            onValueChange={index => setValue(pterms[index])}
                        />
                        <View style={styles.plazos}>
                            <Text style={styles.plazo1}>{A} meses</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.plazo2}>{B} meses</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.plazo3}>{C} meses</Text>
                            {D > 0 ? <Text style={styles.plazo3}>{D} meses</Text>: null }
                        </View>
                        <Text style={styles.slideText}>Su credito por:  ${A}MXN</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.slideText}>Usted recibe:    ${A}MXN</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.slideText}>A un plazo de:  {sliderValue2} meses</Text>

                        <Text style={styles.PaymentText}>Su pago: ${A}.00 MXN</Text>
                    </View>
```

any helpr would be appreciated

Comment: If you're not able to adjust properly data format sent from your backend, you may do [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to turn your string into an array.

Comment: already tried this
const { data } = await ForceApi.post(`/ConsultBCController.php`, {vSolicitudeId, vCreationUser});
            const values = data.terms;
            const obj =JSON.parse(values);

and it throwme undefined

Comment: If you share your response sample, I can adjust my answer accordingly so you will get ***acceptable*** answer ;)

Comment: the  Object.values() didnt work, it splited everything the console log was Array [ "[","2","4",","  "3",
  "6",
  ",",
  "4",
  "8",
  "]",
]

Comment: It could've happened if your source object has properties with empty string (`''`) values. As being said, you may share response sample, so I'll give complete answer. Otherwise, there's a huge room to make all sorts of guesses.

Comment: idk whaet else can i add to the thread, there is all my code onthe first page

Comment: My point was there's a mismatch between the data structure of API response and what your/my code expects it to be. Show me API response sample structure and I'll say how to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that you're attempting to use the data before it arrives, would you use something like:

```
useEffect(() => { 
       const    vCreationUser = 6,
                vSolicitudeId = 8
       ForceApi.post(`/ConsultBCController.php`, {vSolicitudeId, vCreationUser}).then(data => {
            const   values = data.terms,
                    [termA, termB, termC, termD] = values
            setpterms(values)
            setvA(Number(termA))
            setvB(Number(termB))
            setvC(Number(termC))
            setvD(Number(termD))
       })
    }, [])
```

You may combine that with `JSON.parse()` if your API response is not structured properly:

```
const   values = JSON.parse(data.terms),
```

Comment: this throws me 2 errors 1 says that  TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'pterms[0]').  this is should be where i declare  const [value, setValue] = useState(pterms[0]);

Comment: the second one says [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'values.split')]

Comment: I've cleared a clutter a bit, unfortunatelly, without your environment I can't troubleshoot more. However, you need to make sure your response structure matches to what is extracted with above function.

Comment: [Unhandled promise rejection: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "undefined"]

Answer (score 1):

tries to do this but this gives me undefined since it prints the array like this [24,28,32,]

```
const JSONString = values;
   object = JSON.parse(JSONString);
   array = Object.keys(object).map(function(k) {
     return object[k];
   });
```

Comment: There's a shorter way to extract the value of each object property into array: [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Comment: i will try that because what i did helped but it gives me undefined on the last number

Answer (score 0):

Here is a magic code to convert from string to array

```
'[10, 20, 22, 26]'
  .replace(/^\[/gi, '')
  .replace(/\]$/gi, '')
  .split(',')
  .map(v => v.trim())
  .filter(v => v !== "");
```

That would be an array of Strings. If you want an array of Numbers,

```
'[10, 20, 22, 26]'
  .replace(/^\[/gi, '')
  .replace(/\]$/gi, '')
  .split(',')
  .map(v => v.trim())
  .filter(v => v !== "")
  .map(v => Number(v))
  .filter(v => !isNaN(v));
```

Comment: sorry i dont get it, how do i implement that on my code, or how can i acces to the value of that?

Comment: Do you really need to re-invent [the wheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov You are right. I didn't pay attention that initial string was a valid JSON.